# HTML5 video within time frame

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, popcornjs

So I am working on an interactive HTML5 video player, and currently have everything working while using popcorn.js, but I am now trying to go back and make my player work without being dependent on popcorn.js.

When working with popcorn.js, you can use code like:

```
popcorn.code((
    start: 0,
    end: 5,
    onStart: function( options ) {
        //put code here
    }
}}
```

and your code will be executed when the time of your video spans from 0 through 5.  Now, I am trying to have certain blocks of code executed within a certain timeframe of the video, but i can't seem to get it working right and was just wondering if someone can see where i am going about this wrong.

```
while (myVideo.currentTime >= 0 && myVideo.currentTime <= 5)
{
    console.log(myVideo.currentTime);
}
```

This while loop is also running so fast that it causes the browser to slow down and freeze.
However, if i try using an if loop instead of a while loop, it (obviously) only checks it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check fewer than the `while` loop would.

```
var check = setInterval(function() {
    if (myVideo.currentTime >= 5) {
        clearInterval(check);
        console.log("5 seconds reached");
    }
}, 500);
```

You than can start this again when the user pauses and starts over or if he jumps to another time within the timeline.

Comment: Sorry... we both came up with same answer.. Did not see your response until I posted mine.

Comment: I would add a playing check for the video, to only enable this when its actually playing the video, unless, all the page does is play the video, then its not as important.

Comment: thanks to both of you guys!  I was completely going blank on how to handle it, but setInterval makes sense and helps it work properly.

Comment: @nycynik is right. This should of course only be triggered when something is actually playing. :)

Comment: @spooky True that. A typical SO coincidence. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following so your function will run only once every second.

```
setInterval(function(){
if(myVideo.currentTime >= 0 && myVideo.currentTime <= 5){
console.log(myVideo.currentTime);
}
},1000);
```

Good luck!