# Add annotations to a web video

Tags: html, video, web, popcornjs

I would like to implement a web application where you can **upload a video** (e.g. in mp4 format) and **add custom messages** to it or **tag specific frames**. I need to be able to determine the location, size and duration of the balloon containing the text. The interface should be easy enough to use and allow you to add a simple text or a link.

How could I implement this? Is there a platform I could use? Looking around I found this platform called **WireWax** which basically does everything I need, however there is no pricing section and I suspect that you have to contact them directly.

Another interesting product that I found is **Popcorn.js** which allows you to add annotations to videos, but I would have to create from scratch the interface to add messages.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: You could store the information in a database (XY position, time and message and than display the message when the set time has reached during playback. I answered a question lately that could give you an idea on how to do that: [HTML5 video within time frame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651383/1456376)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popcorn.js does indeed have an interface. It's called Popcorn Maker, and it's here:
https://popcorn.webmaker.org/

It's open source, so you can modify it however you like. The source is here: https://github.com/mozilla/butter

Comment: the demo link is broken